Custom Product Extension Translation Not Saving - 400 Bad Request Error
I'm developing a custom product extension for Shopware 6 that includes a translatable field ("headline"). I've followed the recommended steps to set up my entity definitions and migrations, but I'm encountering a 400 Bad Request error when trying to save the product with translations.
My JS Component
const {Component} = Shopware;
const {Criteria} = Shopware.Data;
const Context = Shopware.Context;

import template from "./sw-product-extension-detail-specifications.html.twig";

Component.override('sw-product-detail-specifications', {
    template,

    inject: ['repositoryFactory'],

    data() {
        return {
            productId: null,
            startingAidData: null
        };
    },

    created() {
        this.productId = this.$route.params.id;
        this.loadExtension();
    },

    computed: {
        wucPluginStartingAidExtensionCriteria() {
            const criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.addFilter(Criteria.equals('productId', this.productId));
            return criteria;
        },

        wucPluginStartingAidExtensionRepository() {
            return this.repositoryFactory.create('wuc_plugin_starting_aid_extension');
        }
    },

    methods: {
        loadExtension() {
            this.wucPluginStartingAidExtensionRepository
                .search(this.wucPluginStartingAidExtensionCriteria, Context.api)
                .then(startingAidData => {
                    if (startingAidData.last()) {
                        console.log('Data found', startingAidData.last());
                        this.product.extensions.wucPluginStartingAidExtension = startingAidData.last();
                    } else {
                        console.log('Create and Set New Entity');
                        this.startingAidData = this.wucPluginStartingAidExtensionRepository.create(Shopware.Context.api);
                        this.startingAidData.productId = this.productId;
                        this.startingAidData.headline = 'Test!'
                        this.product.extensions.wucPluginStartingAidExtension = this.startingAidData;

                        console.log(this.product.extensions.wucPluginStartingAidExtension);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error loading extension:', error);
                });
        }
    }
});


Entity Definitions
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace WucPluginStartingAid\Extension\Content\Product;

use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\FkField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\ApiAware;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\PrimaryKey;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\Required;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\IdField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\OneToOneAssociationField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\TranslatedField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\TranslationsAssociationField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\FieldCollection;
use WucPluginStartingAid\Core\Content\StartingAid\Aggregate\StartingAidTranslation\StartingAidTranslationDefinition;

class StartingAidExtensionDefinition extends EntityDefinition
{
    public const ENTITY_NAME = 'wuc_plugin_starting_aid_extension';

    public function getEntityName(): string
    {
        return self::ENTITY_NAME;
    }

    public function getEntityClass(): string
    {
        return StartingAidExtensionEntity::class;
    }

    protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
    {
        return new FieldCollection([
            (new IdField('id', 'Id'))->addFlags(new Required(), new PrimaryKey(), new ApiAware()),
            (new FkField('product_id', 'productId', ProductDefinition::class))->addFlags(new ApiAware()),
            (new TranslatedField('headline'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Required()),

            new OneToOneAssociationField('product', 'product_id', 'id', ProductDefinition::class, false),
            (new TranslationsAssociationField(
                StartingAidTranslationDefinition::class,
                'wuc_plugin_starting_aid_id'
            ))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Required())


        ]);
    }
}


<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace WucPluginStartingAid\Core\Content\StartingAid\Aggregate\StartingAidTranslation;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityTranslationDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\Required;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\StringField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\FieldCollection;
use WucPluginStartingAid\Extension\Content\Product\StartingAidExtensionDefinition;

class StartingAidTranslationDefinition extends EntityTranslationDefinition
{
    public const ENTITY_NAME = 'wuc_plugin_starting_aid_translation';

    public function getEntityName(): string
    {
        return self::ENTITY_NAME;
    }

    public function getEntityClass(): string
    {
        return StartingAidTranslationEntity::class;
    }

    public function getParentDefinitionClass(): string
    {
        return StartingAidExtensionDefinition::class;
    }

    protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
    {
        return new FieldCollection([
            (new StringField('headline', 'headline'))->addFlags(new Required()),
        ]);
    }
}


Error Message
POST http://localhost:8888/api/_action/sync 400 (Bad Request)
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3",
      "status": "400",
      "detail": "This value should not be blank.",
      "source": {
        "pointer": "/write/0/wucPluginStartingAidExtension/translations/2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b/wucPluginStartingAidExtensionId"
      },
      // ... rest of the error message ...
    }
  ]
}

Are there any specific nuances in Shopware 6's translation saving mechanism that I might be missing?
Could there be an issue with the order in which the extension and translation data are being saved?
We set the repo on public if you would like to take a deeper look into it: https://github.com/Wist-Cheng/WucPluginStartingAid/tree/translation
Thanks in advance,
Niklas

Verified entity relationships: The relationship between my main extension entity and its translation entity seems correct
Cleared Shopware cache.
build admin.js etc.

